# What regex to find files with CJK characters using `find` command?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, terminal, find, cjk

The files I'm looking for are of the form `cmn-我.flac`, where the CJK character is variable.

Using `find` command, what regexp should I use to **find all files with a single CJK characters in its name?**

---

**Hints:**
The following regexp find *all* files including those **with and without** CJK characters :

```
find ./ -regex '.*\..*'  # ex: cmn-我.flac
```

Then :

```
find ./ -regex "cmn-.*[\x4e00-\x9fa5]*\.flac"   # the `-` breaks => fails 
find ./ -regex ".*[\x4e00-\x9fa5]*\.flac"       # finds with n CJK characters => we get closer!
find ./ -regex ".*[\x4e00-\x9fa5]{1}\.flac"     # the `{1}` breaks => fails. 
find ./ -regex ".*[\x4e00-\x9fa5]?\.flac"       # the `?` breaks => fails.
```

**How to make it works ?**

Comment: have you tried as workaround for `?` adding capturing group like `([\x4e00-\x9fa5])?`

Comment: @Fede: Doesn't work here. And you ? (the `.*` may be problematic as well as it include CJK characters)

Comment: @Hugolpz please provide more data to test upon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There was an error in the regex, outside of the CJK matching part. The file form to match is **not**

   `cmn-我.flac`

   but **is rather** :

   `./cmn-我.flac`
2. The following command fully works, matching `./cmn-*.flac` where `*` is any single character, **including CJK** :

   `find ./ -regex "./cmn-.\.flac"`
3. The following fully works, matching `./cmn-*.flac` where `*` is any single **CJK character**.

   << NOT yet found ! Help welcome! >>

Comment: Here you're using bash globbing mechanism, you can try `?` instead of `*` to match a single character: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the correct way and need to look a bit more at the [`find` man page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) (e.g. `-regextype`).

### Can't reproduce

```
find ./ -regex "cmn-.*[\x4e00-\x9fa5]*\.xml"
# find: Invalid range end
```

### `find`'s version

First, Be sure to check which version of `find` you're using, there is some differences between implementation:

```
find --version
```

Give:

```
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
…
```

### Explanation

Looking at the `-regex-type` option I only see `POSIX` regular expression types: `emacs` (default), `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep` and `posix-extended`).

Which **[doesn't support custom hex range definition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html)** (compare *Perl* with *POSIX*).

Comment: I got v.4.4.2 as well.