# Linux $FIND and hex notation of Unicode characters' range?

Tags: regex, unicode, find, cjk

I'am unable to get the [unicode hex notation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Hex_notation) working within linux `$find` utility and its `-regex` functionality. There is my case.

Given a folder with 5 files suchs :

```
./cmn-我.flac
./cmn-的.flac
./cmn-三.flac
./cmn-a.flac
./cmn-b.flac
```

To find the files with CJK characters, I tried the following :

```
find ./ -regex "./cmn-.\.flac"                     #Find *ALL* files "*.txt", not what I want.
find ./ -regex "./cmn-[\x4e00-\x9fa5]\.flac"       #fails
find ./ -regex "./cmn-[\u4e00-\u9fa5]\.flac"       #fails
find ./ -regex "./cmn-[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]\.flac"   #fails
find ./ -regex "./cmn-[\u{4e00}-\u{9fa5}]\.flac"   #fails
find ./ -regex "./cmn-[\U0004e00-\U0009fa5]\.flac"  #fails
```

without success.

**How to find the files with CJK characters using `find ./ -regex "[myRegEx]"` and an [unicode hex notation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Hex_notation) regex ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained it in [What regex to find files with CJK characters using `find` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840727/802365) `find` use POSIX regex that doesn't support this kind of pattern.

### Explanation

Looking at the `-regex-type` option I only see `POSIX` regular expression types: `emacs` (default), `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep` and `posix-extended`).

Which **[doesn't support custom hex range definition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html)** (compare *Perl* with *POSIX*).

### Solution

But `grep` does have an **experimental** `-P` or `--perl-regexp` option where you can use this kind of pattern:

```
  find . -name 'cmn-*.flac' -print | grep -P '[\x4e00-\x9fa5]'
```

see [command explanation](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%20-name%20%27cmn-*.xml%27%20-print%20%7C%20grep%20-P%20%27[%5Cx4e00-%5Cx9fa5]%27).

Comment: To get items will **a single** CJK character, I think the following would be more correct : `find . -name 'cmn-*\.flac' -print | grep -P './cmn-[\x4e00-\x9fa5]\.flac'`

Comment: How do you separate `cmn-中.flac` (one CJK character) from `cmn-傷口.flac` (2 CJK characters) ?

Comment: ok. `find . -name 'cmn-*.flac'` finds files with **any number** of (CJK) characters. On my side, `find ./ -regex "./cmn-.\.flac"` finds all the files with `cmn-*.flac`, where * is a **SINGLE** CJK character. Then, your `grep -P '[\x4e00-\x9fa5]'` keeps only the one with at least one CJK, thus excuding `cmn-a.flac`. Also, this combination is a valid answer : `find ./ -regex "./cmn-.\.flac" -print | grep -P '[\x4e00-\x9fa5]'`

Comment: For perfection, I tried to put all the regex into the grep, such as `find ./ -print | grep -P './cmn-[\x4e00-\x9fa5]{1}.flac'`, but doesn't work. Will go for `find ./ -regex "./cmn-.\.flac" -print | grep -P '[\x4e00-\x9fa5]'`

Comment: Stick to `find` to locate your `*.flac` while `grep` should use to extract your chinese characters as its regex are more powerful